# Raspberry Pi Desktop, Guest Additions: Access denied under root

Tags: debian, permissions, virtualization, raspberry-pi-desktop

I've been trying to install Guest Additions for Raspbian Desktop on VirtualBox hosted on Linux. The script won't run even under root. How is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`8.` of the preferred answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286934/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-a-debian-virtual-machine). Not much of an explanation, yet it certainly works.

```
# sh /media/cdrom0/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked for me.

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install build-essential module-assistant dkms

$ sudo m-a prepare
```

then select the menu devices/insert guest...

CD is mounted and select ok

```
$ sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

$ sudo reboot
```

proudly borrowed from, https://www.neontribe.co.uk/debian-virtualbox-guest-additions/

I don't know why root wouldn't work for me sudo -i was enough